# Does 'array.map' preserve the original order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `User` class that `has_many` `Job`s. I map jobs with the following code:

```
def ranges
  user.jobs.map { |u| [u.start_at, u.end_at] }
end
```

I have a spec that compares two arrays:

```
my_array = [[start1, end1], [start2, end2]]
expect(ranges).to eq my_array
```

It passes on local, but not on Bamboo build. I had to change it to pass the build. I still don't understand why it behaves like this. I expect some random pattern even if map doesn't preserve the order.

Why does this pass on my local, but fails in Bamboo build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underlying issue isn't because of `map`, which should preserve the order. Rather, `user.jobs` itself may be in a different order (in each test) since there isn't any explicit `order by` clause used. Without an explicit `order by`, you can't guarantee the order of the jobs even if you create them in a specific order.

You should use http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers:match_array instead of `eq` for comparison to avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks, so its the AR/SQL query result is in a different order, if I understand correctly

Comment: Hi, what does "should preserve the order mean"? Do you mean that it 100% will preserve the order or are there scenarios where it won't? Thanks.