# Are resources defined by an array of titles always evaluated in order?

Tags: puppet

In Puppet, it's possible to define a number of resources using an array of titles, like so:

```
file { ['/some/file1', '/some/file2']:
  ensure => file,
}
```

In terms of **order of application**, is it the same as the following?

```
file { '/some/file1':
  ensure => file,
}
-> file { '/some/file2':
  ensure => file,
}
```

I'm using puppet version 3.8.7, though I am curious if this behavior changes between Puppet 3 / 4 / 5.

I've searched the docs extensively, and while they do talk about defining resources with an array of titles, they don't talk about what order those resources get applied in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a complicated question to answer, but I will split up the question into components to help explain.

**Is this resource array ordering typical behavior in Puppet?**

Yes. To help with this, we need to delve into the Puppet DSL. Since arrays are part of the asymmetric syntax tree portion of the Puppet DSL (and usually for most if not all DSL), we need to check the relevant AST code of the Puppet Parser. The code for the commit at this time of writing is [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/2de165827e11e429235cf4f5b4785ad7049a54ff/lib/puppet/parser/ast/resource.rb#L42). You can change the link to point at your version to see how and if the code has changed to see what the behavior will be for the version of Puppet you are using at any given time.

The code we want to examine is:

```
# Second level of implicit iteration; build a resource for each
# title.  This handles things like:
# file { ['/foo', '/bar']: owner => blah }
resource_titles.flatten.map do |resource_title| # <-- line of iterator
  exceptwrap :type => Puppet::ParseError do
    ...

    if resource.resource_type.is_a? Puppet::Resource::Type
      resource.resource_type.instantiate_resource(scope, resource)
    end
    scope.compiler.add_resource(scope, resource)
    scope.compiler.evaluate_classes([resource_title], scope, false) if fully_qualified_type == 'class'
    resource
  end
end
```

So we see that the array of resources is iterated via the `Array.map()` method in Ruby. This converts the specific question component into "Does the `Array.map()` method in Ruby preserve ordering?". The specific type being iterated upon in the array is the title as specified in the type code when an instance is instantiated. This will typically be a symbol or a string, but the main point of emphasis here is that the iteration is over an array of simple types (i.e. not a nested hash etc.).

The answer to this new question component is also yes as specified in the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) or a simple yes in this [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46901127/5343387).

**Is this resource array ordering a documented supported behavior in Puppet?**

No. You can check the relevant documentation [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_resources_advanced.html#full-syntax) or [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_resources_advanced.html#arrays-of-titles) and see an absence of any mention of this behavior. Also, a former colleague directly asked Puppet about this a few years ago and their high-level response was the same as what I have outlined here thus far.

The code for the resource arrays in the AST can change at any time without warning in the documentation since this is unsupported behavior.

**Should I depend on this unsupported but seemingly always existent behavior?**

Your call. If this is for something like creating nested directories, then the automatic `require` code in Puppet will catch any issues with resources being applied out of order anyway. If not, then you probably need to do a quick cost/benefit calculation on code cleanliness versus potential undefined behavior, mitigated by a code lookup every time you upgrade, plus the time cost of said code lookup.

Comment: I'm afraid I have to disagree with your unqualified "Yes."  I have detailed my position in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> In terms of **order of application**, is it the same as the following?
>
> ```
> file { '/some/file1':
>   ensure => file,
> }
> -> file { '/some/file2':
>   ensure => file,
> }
> ```

Contrary to the claims of the other answer, **NO**, the two are ***not*** equivalent.  Nor does the other answer demonstrate differently.  What it shows is that in Puppet's current implementation, your array-style declaration is equivalent to this:

```
file { '/some/file1':
  ensure => file,
}

# no chain operator here

file { '/some/file2':
  ensure => file,
}
```

Since you specifically ask about order of application, the absence of any explicit relationship between the declared resources is significant.

Now, *by default*, in the absence of an explicit relationship chain between two resources, their relative order of application will be the same as their relative order of evaluation in the manifest set.  But there are two important caveats there:

- That's only a default.  That default order-of-application rule can be changed via [Puppet's 'ordering' setting](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/configuration.html#ordering).  If it is, then your array-based resource declaration cannot be relied upon to produce the same order of application as your alternative using the chain operator.
- Implicit relationships created by the default rule can be overridden or circumvented by explicit ones.  If a contrary chain of one or more explicit relationships were declared in your manifest set, then Puppet would accept and honor it with the array-based declaration, but would reject it as a circular dependency in the case with an explicit chain operator between the resource declarations.

Where relative order of application matters, it is essential to declare explicit relationships.  Array-titled resource declarations do not have such semantics, but you can, in general, add the relationships separately and still obtain the code clarity and brevity advantages of array titles:

```
file { ['/some/file1', '/some/file2']:
  ensure => file,
}

File['/some/file1'] -> File['/some/file2']
```

Comment: I likewise have to disagree with this. While the supporting statements are mostly true, I believe you arrive at the incorrect conclusion from them.

Comment: Well, @MattSchuchard, would you care to elaborate?  The basic question was about whether an array-titled resource declaration is equivalent to a series of separate resource declarations with chain operators in between.  It simply isn't.  The two can produce different compilation and order-of-application behavior -- the latter being specifically what the OP was interested in -- depending on Puppet configuration and the overall manifest set.  Or if you disagree with that, then what is your basis?

Answer (score 1):

There are two interesting answers above which are in disagreement. I will add my 2 cents here, as well as providing some more info that might be interesting to the OP.

The OP has asked *in general* if in terms of order of application:

```
file { ['/some/file1', '/some/file2']:
  ensure => file,
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
file { '/some/file1':
  ensure => file,
}
-> file { '/some/file2':
  ensure => file,
}
```

In general, the answer is "no", as John says.

Here's a simple demonstration to prove that:

Puppet version:

```
$ bundle exec puppet -V
5.3.3
```

My code:

```
# code.pp
include stdlib
$files = range(1, 10).map |$x| { "/tmp/file${x}" }
notice("Files array is: $files")
file { $files:
  ensure =>  file,
}
```

Apply with `--ordering=random`:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --ordering=random code.pp 
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): Files array is: [/tmp/file1, /tmp/file2, /tmp/file3, /tmp/file4, /tmp/file5, /tmp/file6, /tmp/file7, /tmp/file8, /tmp/file9, /tmp/file10]
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.05 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file3]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file9]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file8]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file7]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file6]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file4]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file10]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file5]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.06 seconds
```

Thus, without an explicit relationship declaration, Puppet's random ordering setting sees the resources ordered randomly. If we had explicit orderings declared in the manifest however:

```
# code.pp
file { '/tmp/file1':
  ensure => file,
}
-> file { '/tmp/file2':
  ensure => file,
}
```

The files are always ordered as we want them to be:

```
$ for i in {1..5} ; do rm -f /tmp/file* ; bundle exec puppet apply --ordering=random code.pp ; done
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.21 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.20 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.23 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.22 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.23 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.02 seconds
```

We can also get pseudo-random ordering using Puppet's previous default title-hash ordering, where resources are ordered by a hash generated from the resource title:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --ordering=title-hash code.pp 
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): Files array is: [/tmp/file1, /tmp/file2, /tmp/file3, /tmp/file4, /tmp/file5, /tmp/file6, /tmp/file7, /tmp/file8, /tmp/file9, /tmp/file10]
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.05 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file3]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file6]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file8]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file4]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file7]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file10]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file5]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file9]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.06 seconds
```

But if we switch to manifest ordering we get the files ordered numerically again:

```
$ bundle exec puppet apply --ordering=manifest code.pp 
Notice: Scope(Class[main]): Files array is: [/tmp/file1, /tmp/file2, /tmp/file3, /tmp/file4, /tmp/file5, /tmp/file6, /tmp/file7, /tmp/file8, /tmp/file9, /tmp/file10]
Notice: Compiled catalog for alexs-macbook-pro.local in environment production in 0.05 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file1]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file2]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file3]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file4]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file5]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file6]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file7]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file8]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file9]/ensure: created
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[/tmp/file10]/ensure: created
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.07 seconds
```

I think as John said, Matt's answer is correct, but only assuming that the default ordering of "manifest" is used; and also assuming that none of the resources auto-require other resources.

See also Gary Larizza's post on ordering [here](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2014/10/19/on-dependencies-and-order/).

Comment: Well, here is some actual contradicting evidence. Heuristic evidence, but still evidence. I feel a bit miffed that we were possibly mislead on this, although the version was 3.7.2 at the time, but I feel like manifest ordering did not exist back then.